# Drupal: How to render a span inside a link?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-render

I want this result:

```
<a href="path/to/something">This is a link! <span>with a span inside!</span></a>
```

This renders a link:

```
$render = array(
  'link' => array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t("This is a link!"),
    '#href' => "path/to/something",
  ),
);
```

Why does this not render a span inside the link?

```
$render = array(
  'link' => array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t("This is a link!"),
    '#href' => "path/to/something",
    'span' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => ' <span>with a span inside!</span>',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/930760

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adjust your code to be:

```
$render = array(
  'link' => array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => "<span>" . t("This is a link!") . "</span>",
    '#href' => "path/to/something",
     '#options' => array(
        'html' => TRUE,
    )
  ),
);
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

For the #title property just put the span in it like this: '#title' => t("This is a link! with a span inside!")

Comment: Sadly the span tags in your answer don't show up.  They can be seen by clicking the edit button.